# How to format compressed javascript file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, yui-compressor

I know this question has been asked several times but my question is different because i want to format compressed javascript file. Please tell me that how can i format or beautify compressed/minified javascript file like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) in eclipse.

As i tried to format by ctrl + shift + f but it format only simple javascript file not the compressed file.

I have look around but could not find the solution. Please help :)

**[EDIT 1]** : It is surprising for me that why eclipse does not have that plugin to un-compress the javascript file.